# where is the Tomcat 7 home / lib directory?

Tags: 12.04, tomcat7

When reading manuals / tutorials on setting up JDBC with Tomcat I frequently come across references to the "*Tomcat's HOME\lib*" directory. E.g.:

```
Add the driver to your classpath, to your project, or to Tomcat's HOME\lib directory.
```

Other times, reference is made to the "*$CATALINA_HOME/lib*" directory. E.g.:

```
Before you proceed, don't forget to copy the JDBC Driver's jar into $CATALINA_HOME/lib.
```

I am running Tomcat 7.0.53 and am aware of the following locations:

1. `/usr/share/tomcat7`
2. `/var/lib/tomcat7` (where the `webapps/` directory resides)
3. `/etc/tomcat7`

Of the above location only `/usr/share/tomcat7` contains a `lib` directory with jars. Is this the *"Tomcat's HOME\lib"*  directory? What is then, the `CATALINA_HOME/lib` directory?

Comment: I really don't know the difference, but from to the official documentation as described on the home page 'http://localhost:8080' I can read $CATALINA_HOME/conf/ tomcat_users.xml: so depending of your installation that is the path of 'CATALINA_HOME'.

Comment: What do you get if you run `echo $CATALINA_HOME`?

Comment: @terdon CATALINA_HOME is not exported as an environment variable in my setup.

Comment: Presumably it is only exported to the tomcat user then. OK, if only one of those directories contains a `lib` subdirectory, that's probably the one you want.

Answer (score 13):

Its located user `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib` folder. If you have used `apt-get install tomcat7` command for installing your container.

Answer (score 3):

`CATALINA_HOME` and `Tomcat's HOME` is usually the same:

```
CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
```

`CATALINA_HOME/lib` is therefore `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib`

---

To be sure, search for `bootstrap.jar`. This file is located in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/`

<sub>More details [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)</sub>

Comment: catalina.home designates the command line, bootstrap (bin) and shared library (lib) files. Because these files are usually not changed on a productive server.

catalina.base designates the “personal” files. They are the server configuration files (conf), log and output files (logs), the web application files (webapps) and the temporary working directory (work).

Answer (score 0):

**libs**

```
$ tree /usr/share/tomcat7
/usr/share/tomcat7
├── bin
│   ├── bootstrap.jar
│   ├── catalina.sh
│   ├── catalina-tasks.xml
│   ├── configtest.sh
│   ├── daemon.sh
│   ├── digest.sh
│   ├── setclasspath.sh
│   ├── shutdown.sh
│   ├── startup.sh
│   ├── tomcat-juli.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-juli.jar
│   ├── tool-wrapper.sh
│   └── version.sh
├── defaults.md5sum
├── defaults.template
├── lib
│   ├── annotations-api.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-annotations-api-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── catalina-ant.jar -> ../../java/catalina-ant-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── catalina-ha.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-catalina-ha-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── catalina.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── catalina-jmx-remote.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-catalina-jmx-remote-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── catalina-tribes.jar -> ../../java/catalina-tribes-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── commons-dbcp.jar -> ../../java/commons-dbcp.jar
│   ├── commons-pool.jar -> ../../java/commons-pool.jar
│   ├── el-api.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-el-api-2.2.jar
│   ├── jasper-el.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-jasper-el-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── jasper.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-jasper-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── jsp-api.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-jsp-api-2.2.jar
│   ├── servlet-api.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-servlet-api-3.0.jar
│   ├── tomcat7-websocket.jar
│   ├── tomcat-api.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-api-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── tomcat-coyote.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-coyote-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── tomcat-i18n-es.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-i18n-es-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── tomcat-i18n-fr.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-i18n-fr-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── tomcat-i18n-ja.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-i18n-ja-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── tomcat-jdbc.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-jdbc-7.0.68.jar
│   ├── tomcat-util.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-util-7.0.68.jar
│   └── websocket-api.jar
├── logrotate.md5sum
└── logrotate.template

2 directories, 38 files
```

**webapps**

```
$ tree /var/lib/tomcat7/
/var/lib/tomcat7/
├── common
│   └── classes
├── conf -> /etc/tomcat7
├── logs -> ../../log/tomcat7
├── server
│   └── classes
├── shared
│   └── classes
├── webapps
│   ├── ROOT
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── META-INF
│   │       └── context.xml
└── work -> ../../cache/tomcat7
```

and **config**

```
tree /etc/tomcat7/
/etc/tomcat7/
├── Catalina
│   └── localhost
│       ├── docs.xml
│       ├── examples.xml
│       ├── host-manager.xml
│       └── manager.xml
├── catalina.properties
├── context.xml
├── logging.properties
├── policy.d
│   ├── 01system.policy
│   ├── 02debian.policy
│   ├── 03catalina.policy
│   ├── 04webapps.policy
│   ├── 10examples.policy
│   └── 50local.policy
├── server.xml
├── tomcat-users.xml
└── web.xml
```